# Parsing an XML getting through HttpPOST in android

Tags: java, android

During the execution of a httpPOST i store the response as a String and the response i am getting is like this:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <string xmlns="http://localhost:4471/">101~Success</string>
```

i just want to get 101~Success after parsing so that i can get 101 by using split function but am not able to get this element in android.I was getting this in J2ME as:

```
            InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(strResponse.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(in);
            parser = new XmlParser(is);
            doc.parse( parser );

            Element root = doc.getRootElement();
            Element item = doc.getElement(2);
            String parsedResponse = item.getText(0);
```

How can i do it in android?

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the XMl Using [DOM](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=152)
or [DOM](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/)
or [XMLPULLParser](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidXML/article.html)

Comment: I am new to xml;can u explain a little bit.I have tried using DOM but will u tell me what should i mention in TagName